# Getting app logs off of a Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: android, logging, android-studio

I do testing on app that I download from Jenkins as a .apk file. I have Android Studio and I have gotten as far as connecting my Samsung galaxy S6, setting it to debugging mode and I can see a bunch of device logs coming up at the bottom of my Android Studio screen.

What I cannot figure out is how to see the logs for the app I am testing. I have tried to filter the logs by using the app name. Do I need to filter the logs using a specific file name? Maybe the file used to install the app? Is there an easy way to get the app logs from my device that I am not seeing?

Comment: If you launched the app from within android studio, then it should automatically select that app from the list in the log viewer (or else it should be available to select).

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that:

1. This is the debug version of the app.
2. Proguard isn't set up to strip out certain logs.
3. ADB Integration is enabled.[image]
4. Sometimes, you have cycle through the USB options (For example, my LG phone needed to be in PTP mode before Android Studio picked it up)

For obvious security reasons, most apps don't want the public to access their logs.